# Como criar um sistema notificações em tempo real semelhante ao Stack Overflow?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema Help Desk, e gostaria de algumas idéias de como criar um sistema de notificação semelhante ao próprio Stack Overflow, sempre que algum novo suporte for cadastrado.

Pretendo utilizar PHP, MySQL e jQuery apenas.

Devo utilizar o `window.setTimeout` para verificar no banco de tempos em tempos se um novo chamado for registrado?

Comment: O Stack Overflow usa websockets para notificações em tempo real.

Comment: Alguma das respostas lhe ajudou? Ou há problemas nelas? Comente informando ao autor qual a duvida em tentar usar a solução proposta. Se alguma das respostas lhe resolveu o problema, marque-a como correta clicando em ✓

Answer (score 17):

Acabei de responder uma pergunta parecida, só que falava sobre um chat.

As opções que têm são as seguintes:

Para implementar o chat:

- a opção que vai te dar a maior abrangência em termos de browseres, é chamada de **long-polling**, mas também é a que vai dar mais trabalho. Veja mais sobre a técnica: [long-polling](http://rberaldo.com.br/server-push-long-polling-php-ios/)
- um outra opção que vai ser mais fácil, é usar **websocket**, e criar uma conexão com servidor, que vai poder enviar mensagens quando algum evento do chat ocorrer... tipo enviar uma mensagem, mas nesse caso o servidor terá de ser capaz de receber a conexão do cliente via websocket (terá de ser capaz de esperar por conexões... basta buscar por "php websocket" no google que aparecem algumas bibliotecas).

Answer (score 13):

Cara, **NÃO** utilize ajax com setInterval.
Veja, imagine que de 1 em 1 minuto o sistema irá fazer uma requisição ao servidor e retornar uma resposta ao browser, mesmo que não haja mudanças na conversa.
Se houver vários clientes, irá sobrecarregar o sistema com requisições em ajax, o que seria desperdício de recursos.

Procure sobre PHP+LONG POLLING.
Long Polling funciona diferente do ajax, a conexão fica aberta aguardando uma resposta do servidor.

O ideal mesmo seria implementar essa parte em nodejs, uma vez que é mais adequando para aplicações real time.

Answer (score 1):

Você já pensou em utilizar algum tipo de sistema de Pusher notification como por exemplo o `Pusher` ou o `PubNub` ?

Você utilizar timeout você vai estar fazendo `Long Polling` e esse tipo de atualização utiliza muito mais recurso.

Minha sugestão para você seria você dar uma olhada na melhor opção:

- [www.meteor.com](http://www.meteor.com)
- [socket.io](http://socket.io)
- [pusher.com](http://pusher.com)
- [www.pubnub.com](http://www.pubnub.com)

Comment: o que fazem o `Pusher` e o `PubNub` exatamente?

Comment: Os dois fornecem um serviço de Push notification baseado em WebSocket. A vantagem de usar esses dois é que eles diversos tipos de API para integração no seu sistema. A base é que você vai criar um canal e quando esse canal for invocado ele vai executar um handler.

Comment: Exemplo: http://pubnub.github.io/backbone/