# Como criar um sistema de notificação semelhante ao facebook

Tags: php, html, html5

Sou iniciante e preciso desenvolver um sistema para controle de tarefas em `php`. Gostaria que este sistema tivesse um ícone no canto superior direito, que mostraria um número de tarefas vencidas/vencem naquele dia para o usuário, similar às notificações do `facebook`.

Existe algo pronto que possa utilizar?

Comment: O que você tentou?

Comment: Neste vídeo tem uma solução em php + javascript que pode ser útil https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFFJeHw6VBU. Esta pergunta aqui no SOpt talvez também seja útil http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9475/notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-tempo-real-semelhante-ao-stack-overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testei o código e está funcionando. Qualquer dúvida é só perguntar.

### `index.php`

```
!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title></title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>     
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function atualizarTarefas() {
           // aqui voce passa o id do usuario
           var url="get.php?id=1";
            jQuery("#tarefas").load(url);
        }
        setInterval("atualizarTarefas()", 1000);
        </script>   
 </head>
 <body>
INFORMACAO EH EXIBIDA AQUI: <div id="tarefas"></div> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

### `get.php`

```
<?php 
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'tarefas');

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $sql = "select * from tarefas where id = $id";

    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

        $retorna = $resultado['vencidas'];
        echo $retorna;
?>
```

Comment: `[...]tarefas vencidas/vencem naquele dia`... Fazer requisições para verificar as tarefas que venceram ou vão vencer **no dia** é um desperdício exagerado. Se o usuário logou de manhã e não houver notificação, a próxima verificação será ao fim do dia, não no segundo seguinte!