# Verificar banco de dados em tempo real com JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Queria fazer um sistema em que temos uma página em branco e quando fosse colocado alguma coisa numa tabela do banco de dados o JavaScript automaticamente exibisse o resultado na pagina sem dar refresh, ou seja sem dar f5 na página.

Como faço isso?

Comment: pesquisa sobre ajax cron job, para obter informações para o que você precisa.

Comment: Pesquise por [tag:ajax].

Comment: Isso está relacionado ao _Long Polling_ : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9475/notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-tempo-real-semelhante-ao-stack-overflow/10109#10109

Answer (score 2):

Pode tentar o seguinte:
Usar o método [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) para chamar um script via [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) a cada X período. O conteúdo ajax pode carregado em qualquer lugar da página sem a necessidade de recarregá-la, dentro de um div por exemplo.

Uma forma de implementar isto é criando dois arquivos:

A - um arquivo html principal, que conterá o DIV onde o conteúdo AJAX será carregado e o código javascript que fará a chamada ao AJAX a cada X período de tempo.

B - um arquivo php que será chamado via ajax e que consultará e retornará o conteúdo do banco.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: BOa tarde, pode me dar um exemplo de codigo?