# Real time com javascript ou jquery?

Tags: php, javascript

Eu preciso ativar notificações de mensagens em uma página web,

Exemplo,

Usuário recebe uma mensagem e eu notifico ele que tem uma nova mensagem mas sem atualizar a página.

Como posso fazer uma função que execute a cada dois ou três segundo um ajax para verificar se há uma nova mensagem disponível?

Comment: Se quer ajax utilize o método de ajax polling, usando o `setInterval`, o ideal entretanto seria utilizar o  Websockets, ele é muito mais econômico e performático, porém é mais complexo e o *PHP não lida tão bem com isto*, porém pode tercerizar isto utilizando o Pubnub, Pusher, Ably.io, ScaleDrone, Hydna, Google Drive Real Time...

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9475/notificações-em-tempo-real-semelhante-ao-stack-overflow/10109

Comment: @Inkeliz obrigado, precisava de algo simples mesmo e sua resposta atende bem a minha pergunta.

Comment: websockets é uma tecnologia bem melhor pra isso, mas só é compatível com os browsers mais atuais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a função setInterval, [documentação aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

por exemplo para executar sua função a cada 3 segundos

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        window.onload = function() {            

        function funcaoAjax(){
          console.log('Executando');
            

        }
            var intervalo = setInterval(funcaoAjax,3000);
}
        //-->
        </script>
```

para parar a execução use o método clearInterval. [documentação aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

```
clearInterval(intervalo );
```