# tem como fazer a requisição só quando houver alteração no banco de dados? ao invés de verificar cada segundo

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

  function atualizarTarefas() {


    $("#header").load("<?=site_url('home/notificar/')?>");
   }
    setInterval("atualizarTarefas()", 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: Tem, a melhor maneira é utilizando Websockets, *entretanto pode também utilizar long-polling, assim permanece com uma conexão ativa e somente encerra quando houver atualização, então cria uma nova*. Veja em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9475/notifica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-tempo-real-semelhante-ao-stack-overflow/10109. O PHP por padrão oferece suporte para Websockets, mas não é uma tarefa tão simples, *embora existam algumas bibliotecas*, você pode usar websockets usando o Pubnub, Pusher, Ably.io, ScaleDrone, Hydna que será bem mais fácil.

Comment: okay vou tentar entender mais do assunto, Websockets valeu pela dica!