# Atualizar função PHP a cada segundo

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou usando uma função para obter o load do servidor:

```
function get_server_cpu_usage(){
    $load = sys_getloadavg();
    return $load[1];
}
```

Chamo ela com:

```
<div id="load"><?= get_server_cpu_usage(); ?></div>
```

Eu preciso implementar algo para atualizar essa informação a cada segundo, sem que a página fosse atualizada, algo como o setTimeout ou setInterval do JS.

Como posso fazer isso nesse caso?

Comment: Se queres mesmo utilizar PHP, o melhor seria implementar o [long polling](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10109/6630).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vai ter que criar um PHP separado (cpu.php):

```
    $load = sys_getloadavg();
    echo $load[1];
```

---

No *cabeçalho* (HEAD) do **HTML**:

```
<script>
window.onload = cpuUsage();
function cpuUsage(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           document.getElementById("cpu_usage").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
    xhttp.send();
    //Repetir após 5 segundos
    setTimeout(function(){ cpuUsage(); }, 5000);
}
</script>
```

---

No *corpo* (Body) do **HTML**:

```
<div id="cpu_usage">-----</div>
```

Eu aconselho mais tarde melhorar esse a parte PHP colocando um método de autenticação evitando sobrecarga ou acesso direto do arquivo, podendo ser acessado apenas pelo AJAX com um parametro GET correto ou método de **token**.

Answer (score 0):

Assim diretamente, como a função que deseja está no back, não será possível.
Para conseguir resolver, pode colocar esta função para executar num script a parte e chamar com um ajax.

Por exemplo (Ou algo assim):

```
$.get('http://teste.com.br/funcao.php', function(){

});
```

Comment: Só existe essa forma? Não há como fazer diretamente na página?

Comment: Neste caso não. Veja, sua função foi escrita em PHP, correto? O PHP executa no back end. Já o JS executa no front. Na verdade, no cliente. Não há como o JS interferir ou chamar o PHP diretamente. Desta forma, não sei se é viavel, mas ou você chama como eu motrei ou faz essa função novamente porém em js.

Comment: É um problema arquitetural da WEB mesmo. Funcionamento dela.

Comment: Como converto essa função em JS?

Comment: Bom pelo que vi, você pega informações do servidor não é? De qualquer forma, como essa info você só vai obter do lado do server, eu retornaria em formato de JSON, apenas a informação que deseja exibir. Na requisição ajax, eu receberia a informação e exibiria, ou faria o que bem entendesse. Aí sim, com o intervalo de tempo que deseja. Infelizmente, é a única forma de fazer sem dar postback